# Can't register site with facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication

I want to install a Facebook login on my site, so I go here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

I have to register my site so I click the link and go here:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/

I choose Website option, but it takes me back to where I just was:
developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
Yes I am logged while I am doing this.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ in this page,  simply click create new app on the right corner.